# Cost of VPS administration

Tags: hosting

I am working on a Django-Ajax commercial web app for which, I am convinced that I need to go for VPS hosting. However, I'd like to outsource the server administration part.

Can you guys please explain if I can get VPS administration services in the market?

If yes, how much will it cost? Will it cost a periodical fees, like $$/months? I reside in India and would really appreciate if someone shows light on this topic in the context of Indian Market.

If it helps, I have decided to go with Slicehost.com and have already purchased the domain name. I have studied there plans, but need to know cost for server administration if I outsource it.

Please excuse me if serverfault.com is not the right place to ask this kind of question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out webhostingtalk.com

There you will find all the info you need about hosting and services.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have searched WHT, but could not get something similar to my question. I have posted same que over there as well. I am on tight schedule.

Comment: different levels of cost are associated with different levels of administration. The key phrase here is "managed hosting"

I would recommend a single host, but don't think that would be helpful.

look through this: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=Google+Search&q=managed+hosting+administration

Comment: I got similar answers from WHT. http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?p=6245911#post6245911
I will be able to make a decision now. Thanks for your time. :)